# inverting the remainder using loop in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm trying to reverse the remainders I got but the reversing LOOP isn't working well.

I've tried to change the loops. at first i tried to use while loop and nested for loop. it gave the result but it didn't reverse the result i got which means the **nested for loop** didn't work properly.

```
{

    int n,i,rem;
    string str="",str1="";
`{    
 cout<<"enter decimal Number:";
    cin>>n;
    while(n>0)`

    {rem=n%2;
    str=to_string(rem);
        n=n/2;
            str=str+str1;
             for(i=str.length()-1;i>=0;i--)}
    {
        cout<<str[i];

    }}
```

Comment: 1. Get an IDE or text editor and let it format the code for you.
2. Please add expected and actual output instead of only "it doesn't work"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  The code you've posted won't compile, please post actual code and exactly what's wrong so we can try to help you.

Comment: As an idea: `str=str+str1;` is probably meant to be `str1=str+str1;` because you overwrite `str` in every iteration of the loop, but never change `str1`, also you probably don't want to print the number in a _nested_ loop, because it will print parts of the reversed number beofre you even calculated the whole reversed number?

Comment: You are reversing binarily. As is, `0b1`, `0b10`, `0b100` will all produce the same number, apart from leading zeros. On the otherhand, why not reverse `0b1` to e. g. `0b1000`? Wouldn't you rather want to reverse all `sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT` bits? That would produce a nice bijective function for the entire set of binary numbers... With that, you could easily operate on integers only, just with bitshifts and AND operations.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and format you code accordingly.

Comment: @churchill it aint reversing the result. For instance, i enter decimal 11 and i should be having 1011. instead it gives 1101 which means my WHILE LOOP is executing in proper way. But For Loop isnt performing its task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the  solution to your problem

```
    while(n>0)
{
    rem=n%2;
    str1=to_string(rem);
    n=n/2;
    str=str+str1; }
    for(i=str.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        cout<<str[i];

    }
```

actually when you are taking mod with 2 in rem and then storing it in str (string) in the next step you add nothing in str (str=str+str1.. you are adding str in to str) because str1 have nothing stored in it. store the remainder in str1 and then concatenate it into str string. then reverse the str string in whcih you have overall concatenated the strings..
regards
zain ahmad

Comment: does it matter whether we store output in str1 or in str. lets suppose my code `str=to_string(rem);` . I'm storing my output in str. Str1 is empty here. And in your code you are storing in str1. does it matter whether we store it in str1 or str because either way one string is going to be empty.

Comment: no actually my vision is something else. i am asking that actually adding or concatenating string matters, you are saying true that it does not matters that whether in which string you are storing, actually adding value of str in str does not gives meaning. adding or concatenating value of str in str1 gives the right solution, in your solution it is same as str=str+str1 how ever in the whole program there is nothing changes in str1. values are changing in str no in str1. so store remainder in str1 and add str1 to str or store value of remainder in str and add it into str1 both gives the same.